# express mongoose : getting aggregate returns empty array

Tags: express, mongoose, aggregate

Dears,

I'm having trouble in getting back mongoDB aggregation, using mongoose.

The query in MongoDB is sending back data, but the call from mongoose always returns empty array

**UPDATE**
**I found the fix, I have to add a 3rd parameter when setting the model**

```
const RawData = mongoose.model('rawdata', rawDataSchema, 'rawdata');
```

Here is the code

**Schema rawdata.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const rawDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    Email: String,
    Nb: Number,
    Licences: String,
    Licence_ret: String,
    Pays: String,
    Share: String,
    Pack: String,
    Quota_in_MB: Number,
    Webmail_Ext: Number, });


const RawData = mongoose.model('rawdata', rawDataSchema);

export default RawData;
```

**index.js - edited after first feedbacks**

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import RawData from 'rawdata'

const app = express();

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    const data = await RawData.aggregate(
        [
            { "$group": { _id: { license: "$Licence_Carrefour" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    License: "$_id.license",
                    count: 1
                }
            }
        ]);
    console.log('data', data)
    res.send('hello')
});

(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, err => {
        if (err) console.log('\x1b[31m%s', 'DB is not connected');
        console.log('connected to database ');
    });

    app.listen(APP_PORT, () => console.log('app up'));
})();
```

Comment: thks. When keeping only the callback, the result is empty...

Comment: seems the problem is in the query, because the result is always an empty array.

Comment: yes thks a lot. But now results is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184957/discussion-between-iagowp-and-jerome).